# Add auto incrementing key prop to Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, key, react-native-flatlist

How to add incrementing key for Flatlist renderItem, way it is for map:

```
.map((data,key) => <Component data={data} key={key}/>
```

Right now I have it like this, but key doesn't show up in MyComponent props:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <MyComponent data={item} />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item,key) => key}
/>
```

Comment: Would you like to precise your desired result?

Comment: I would like to have a prop for each item called key(or whatever) and the value should be incremented numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5... (according to the list items count)

Answer (score 1):

The `key` doesn't show up because you aren't supposed to have access to it in the component. *This is by design.* See [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2429), specifically [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2429#issuecomment-61008642), explaining the reasoning behind it. To quote with the most relevant sections pertaining to your question **bolded**:

> The reason is that the concept of a key is something that is
>   controlled by React internals before your component gets created. The
>   same thing for refs.
>
> You can think about an array of ReactElements as a Map.
>
> A Map is a series of key and value tuples. A React fragment is a
>   series of key and props tuples (and also type and ref). The key is
>   designed to decide what the value is in each slot, but not the actual
>   value itself.
>
> **If you're reading a prop named key you might be overloading the
>   meaning of key or accidentally using it for something unrelated.**
>
> This change makes the concept a bit more strict. This helps avoids
>   bugs with transferring props to another component which shouldn't
>   bring the key and ref along with it. It also helps performance by
>   ensure that types in React internals are consistent and stable.
>
> **I would suggest renaming or duplicating the prop name as a possible
>   fix if you really need to access it.**

If for some reason you *absolutely need* the `key` prop's value, then please edit your question for the reasoning on why. There are workarounds (see inside the Github issue), but for a good answer, we would need to understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

---

To answer the comment, if all you want is the index value, then just pass along `index` as a prop as stated in the [documentation for FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem) for `renderItem`:

```
renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
  <MyComponent
    data={item}
    indexKeyIdOrWhatever={index}
  />
)}
```

Comment: Hey Michael thanks for the answer, this is what I am trying to achieve: _I would like to have a prop for each item called key(or whatever) and the value should be incremented numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5... (according to the list items count)_

Comment: @nikasv But why? For what purpose is it? I'll edit in an answer if you just want the index value, but as it stands, your question is really something that you could have answered by reading the docs if this was the case. Also, you should be editing these comments into your question to make it more clear as it would help others who later see this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the `Array#map` function works, actually. The second argument in the callback function stands for `index`, which is basically a counter. It starts at `0` to this is actuall what you want.

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const numbers = arr.map((item, index) => index);

console.log(numbers);
```

**[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you want to render a list of `<MyComponent />` inside `<FlatList />`?

```
const FlatList = ({ data }) => data.map((item, i) => (
  <MyComponent item={item} key={i} />
))
```

Answer (score 0):

to add a key to FlatList You need to add it in the object

```
items = [{key: 1, name: 'name1'}, {key: 2, name: 'name2'}, ... ]
```

not as a prop like

```
<Item key={1} />
```

so basically `this.state.data` will contain items array each object will contain key and then

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Item name={item.name} />}
  />
```

you can add the key to object by `items.map((item, index)=>{ item.key = index })`
or you can use id or any thing else unique coming from API

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <MyComponent data={item} />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item,key) => key}
/>
```

`{ item }` was converted into `{ item, index }`.